# Jquery smooth scroll jumps upon first load i with fixed side bar

Tags: jquery, user-interface, scroll, scrollto

Right now, I'm just using the css-tricks scroll to jquery code, but I'm running into a really strange problem.

Upon first opening the site and clicking on the fixed links on the side bar, the `scrollto` will jump during smooth scroll. If you click the same sidebar navigation link twice the page scrolls to the part of the page that initiates the skip.

HOWEVER, this is where it gets strange. If you click on the logo of my site in the top left of the page and try clicking on the sidebar links, the links work perfectly with no problem at all.

I am not familiar with Jquery at all. I just thought this would be a nice simple way to animate information on my page.

Here is my site running with the problem:

[hivizdesign.com](http://hivizdesign.com)

Remember: the first time you load the page, the `scrollto` function skips, but after clicking on the logo `scrollto` works perfect.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
$(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000, function() {
  location.hash = target;
});
```

To:

```
 $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000, function() {     
    if(history.pushState) {
        history.pushState(null, null, target);
    }
    else {
        location.hash = target;
    }
});
```